# How to integarate the bugzilla with netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, bugzilla

I want to integrate bugzilla to with the netbeans 8.0. I input the "Task Repository URL" of my server URL http://www.myowenserver.com/bugzilla/, after fill the username and password and then click the validate button, but, it always occur the "Validation failed".

Comment: Did you find an answer? Id'be very interested, because I'm having the same problem. I've set up Bugzilla successfully but I'm not able to connect NetBeans to it. My setup originally included HTTP basic authentication and a self-signed SSL certificate. Even after disabling those, NetBeans couldn't connect to the instance. Using the web browser I had no problems. I didn't find a tutorial on how to connect NetBeans to a self-hosted Bugzilla instance.

Comment: I came closer by installing most of the "missing" optional perl modules, which you can see by running `./checksetup.pl`. At least I was able to see the bugs in NetBeans, despite (!) self-signed SSL cert but only with disabled (!) basic auth. But submitting/changing bugs didn't work. NetBeans then shows the "Edit Task Repository" dialog again, where the problem begins from the start.

Comment: I was using NetBeans 8.0.2 (Windows) and BugZilla 4.4.9 (Debian Wheezy).

Answer (score 0):

This original article may help: [Netbeans Bug-Tracking Tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/73/ide/kenai-issuetracking.html)

Also try https:// in your URL.

You can test connection on Netbeans Bugzilla Community (Bugzilla for Netbeans bugs):

- Sign in at netbeans.org
- Create repository in Netbeans IDE and put there:

  - https://netbeans.org/buzilla/,
  - login
  - password
- Push Validate to check connection.
- In Netbeans IDE: Services - Task Repositories - Netbeans repository - Find Tasks - you are hopefully in.